# WebClient returning error 500 on GET request MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I'm having an issue with the WebClient. I'm using API-key authentication, and the API-key is indeed legit. If I turn off authentication on my API it gets the data without any issues, however, if I enable checking for "Authentication" in the WebClient header, it returns a 401 with a wrong/invalid API-key, but with a valid one it returns error 500.

Code with the WebClient:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Clear();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", AppSettings.ApiKey());
        client.Headers.Add("Host", "localhost");
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        var newsJson = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:59308/Api/ListNews");
        var newsJsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<News>>(newsJson);
        ViewData["NewsFeed"] = newsJsonDeserialized.ToList();
    }
    var dayMessages = new List<string> { "an astonishing", "an amazing", "a beautiful", "a gorgeous", "a loving" };
    var randomNumber = new Random().Next(dayMessages.Count);
    ViewData["DayOfWeekMsg"] = dayMessages[randomNumber] + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
    return View();
}
```

ApiController:

```
public ActionResult ListNews()
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        var apiToken = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        var apiTokens = db.ApiTokens.ToList();
        var websiteUrl = Request.Url.Host;
        if (apiTokens.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Token == apiToken && i.WebsiteUrl == websiteUrl) == null)
        {
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
        var news = db.News;
        var newsList = news.ToList();
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newsList, Formatting.Indented), "application/json");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is downstream of the `return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();` call.  Most likely, the serializer is having trouble serializing your data.  Recommend you break up that code a little and step through it.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Thank you for commenting so fast, however, I get the serialized output just fine, provided that I have no Authorization on it, so that part should work fine. As to the authorization itself, when entering a wrong API-key in the WebClient's header, it returns a 401 as supposed. When entering a valid API-key it returns the 500 which is what I can't make any sense of.

There is indeed something wrong somewhere, but the serializer I don't think is the problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: Error code 500 means there is something wrong on server. Debugging server code may give you some clue.

Comment: @PankajKapare - Indeed, but I'm kinda lost on how to approach the debugging on the server end, this is my first attempt to really use JSON. The project is currently only ran locally so the server would be my local pc, how would I debug this?

Comment: What I would suggest is to isolate issue, in Webclient code just hardcode value of JSON response which otherwise you would have got by calling you WebAPI. This will help to isolate if your client code is breaking or server server code (WebApi) is breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same problem but I was receiving a 500 and I fixed by setting the accept language header (with UserAgent):

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en");
```